# Reading from a QFile in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qfile

What would be the optimal way of reading from a `QFile` that resides in a different thread than the one I want to read from?

Consider:

```
class AFile : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AFile(const QString &name, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent), m_File(name) { m_File.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite); }

public slots:
    void write(const QByteArray &data, qint64 pos) { m_File.seek(pos); m_File.write(data); }

private:
    mutable QFile m_File;
};

class AData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;

    void save(const QByteArray &data) { emit saveData(data, 0); }

signals:
    void saveData(const QByteArray &data, qint64 pos) const;
};

AFile file("myfile");
AData data;
QThread *thread = new QThread;

connect(&data, &AData::saveData, &file, &AFile::write);

file.moveToThread(&thread);
thread.start();
data.save("Some data");

//how to concurrently read though?
```

`AFile` is a wrapper around `QFile` that handles all writes to the file. It is moved to a different thread in order to not slow the main thread with expensive disk write operations. Multi-thraeded read situations are handled by locks or mutex but that would defeat the purpose of having the file in the different thread in the first place since the main one (wanting to read from it) will have to wait for the write to finish so in such a case I may leave it in the main thread to begin with.

The option I do not quite like are signals and slots because it seems to me a bit heavy weight. I would basically send a request for the data and wait for it to be read (either returning the data via signal or sending variable to be filled with the data and waiting for a signal it has been finished).

After some consideration this seems to be the best approach but I am not really sure it is a good design.

Comment: Are the writes to file really slowing down your app? I would expect the OS to cache them, unless you forced some synchronized mode. Also do I understand correctly that you want to read and write the file independently without synchronization? I assume you are reading and writing at different parts of it. Then you could simply open the file twice, once for reading and once for writing.

Comment: @michalsrb All synchronous I/O perfomed from the GUI thread is a major cause of usability problems and GUI hangs - it has been so since day 1 of event-loop-driven UI APIs. That's the reason why modern APIs such as Universal Windows Platform has primarily asynchronous APIs: if the UI blocks waiting for any I/O, you give your user bad experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concurrent reading is done by splitting the request and indication parts: you first request the data, the reader reads it, then you react to the indication that a data was read.

Since the file object is accessed from a worker thread, I've encapsulated it inside the `AData` class. You can move the class to a worker thread, the signals you call from outside are thread-safe.

It should also be possible to make an asynchronous wrapper around a `QFile`, but doing it properly would require using Qt's implementation details (`core_private` module).

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/async-file-io-39226814
#include <QtWidgets>

class AData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QFile m_file;
public:
    explicit AData(QObject * parent = nullptr) : QObject{parent} {
        connect(this, &AData::save, this, [=](const QByteArray & data, qint64 pos){
            m_file.seek(pos);
            m_file.write(data);
        });
        connect(this, &AData::load, this, [=](qint64 pos, qint64 len){
           m_file.seek(pos);
           if (len == -1) len = m_file.size();
           auto data = m_file.read(len);
           emit loaded(data, pos);
        });
    }
    bool open(const QString & name) {
        m_file.setFileName(name);
        return m_file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    }
    Q_SIGNAL void save(const QByteArray &data, qint64 pos = 0) const;
    Q_SIGNAL void load(qint64 pos, qint64 len) const;
    Q_SIGNAL void loaded(const QByteArray &data, qint64 pos) const;
};
```

A test UI demonstrates how to use it:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    struct Thread : QThread {
        ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); }
    } ioThread;
    AData data;
    data.open("myfile");
    data.moveToThread(&ioThread);
    ioThread.start();

    QWidget ui;
    QGridLayout layout{&ui};
    QTextEdit text;
    QPushButton load{"Load"};
    QPushButton save{"Save"};
    QPushButton clear{"Clear"};
    layout.addWidget(&text, 0, 0, 1, 2);
    layout.addWidget(&load, 1, 0);
    layout.addWidget(&save, 1, 1);
    layout.addWidget(&clear, 2, 0, 1, 2);
    ui.show();

    using Q = QObject;
    Q::connect(&load, &QPushButton::clicked, &data, [&]{
        data.load(0, -1);
    });
    Q::connect(&data, &AData::loaded, &app, [&](const QByteArray & data, qint64){
       text.setPlainText(QString::fromUtf8(data));
    });
    Q::connect(&save, &QPushButton::clicked, &data, [&]{
        data.save(text.document()->toPlainText().toUtf8());
    });
    Q::connect(&clear, &QPushButton::clicked, &text, &QTextEdit::clear);

    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: This is pretty nice and concise! I have a question though, does not this use of QtConcurrent introduce race condition? Suppose that write is executing and is dispatched by QtConcurrent into some thread. Before it finishes there is read dispatched and to the same location as well. What will happen? Does QtConcurrent guard against this situation somehow? m_File is the shared resource here as I understand it.

Comment: It is a shared resource and I'm not sure whether `QFile` is resilient against such access or not. It is possible to ensure that only one access is executing at a time, I will edit it in later.

Comment: I have already tried it and it is not resilient to it. To solve it I first tried locking but eventually returned to not using QtConcurrent and moving the wrapper to single other thread because that way it is not slowing the main (GUI) thread and has no "locking" overhead because it is guaranteed all accesses are never parallel as they are all executed in single thread. I am looking forward to your solution though (likely better than mine :-) ).

Comment: Thankfully, the modifications needed to switch from a thread pool to a dedicated thread are minimal.